# reusing socket streams

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server socket that I setup, and a client socket that connects to the server socket.

In the following sequence:

1. I open an ObjectOutputStream from the client to the server
2. On the server I open an ObjectInputStream from the accepted socket connection from the client
3. On the Server I open an ObjectOutputStream using the accepted socket connection from the client
4. On the client I open an ObjectInputStream

Everything works without error. 
In a loop on the server I have the following

```
while(true) {
Map<Integer,Game> games = GameEngine.getGames();
System.out.println("Games is: " + games + " size is " + games.size());
secondaryOutputStream.writeObject(games);
secondaryOutputStream.flush();
// sleep for 2 seconds then send the games again
try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(4000);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

the secondaryOutputStream is the ObjectOutputStream from the server to the client.
What I am doing here is writing a map to the client. I do this repeatedly in a loop as you can see, using the same ObjectOutputStream.

There are no exceptions, so all the connections are sound. However, on the client side, I only receive the map once, after the socket connection is established with the server. If the map is updated and written to the client, I still see the original map values, when the server **first** wrote the map to the client. Can you reuse Object streams in this manner? Thanks indeed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ObjectOutputStream has a space saving (and identity preserving) feature where it keeps track of objects previously sent (based on object identity), and does not resend them.  instead, it just sends a marker which indicates which object it previously sent, and the ObjectInputStream (which keeps a handle to all objects sent) just re-returns that object on the other end.  you need to use `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` between each send so that the object will be completely resent.  you can also use `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`, but this may not function exactly how you need.

Comment: That fixed my problem. I called 'reset()' and it works perfect. Thank you so much for this!